# Negative match RewriteCond not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, match

I'm experimenting with an idea and trying to keep Yahoo Slurp-bot on my website but redirect everyone else via a 301 redirect. I cannot get a negative match. Sending Slurp to site2.com and keeping everyone else on site1.com like this works fine:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} site1.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Slurp
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.site2.com [L,R=301]
```

The opposite doesn't:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} site1.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !Slurp
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.site2.com [L,R=301]
```

The user-agent is 100% correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> keeping everyone else on site1.com

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?site1\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !Slurp [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.site2.com/$1 [L,R=301,NE]
```

Comment: Did you mean to put 'site2.com' in the second instance where you put site1.com (on the last line) ? Because this doesn't work, if you did. For me it just keeps everyone on site1.com regardless of user-agent.

Comment: But did you not want `keeping everyone else on site1.com`?

Comment: I believe you want `if (Slurp) => site2.com else site1.com` right?

Comment: I also had typo that I fixed in my answer.

Comment: Sorry, no. I want to keep Slurp useragent on this page, but nobody else. They will be redirected to site2.com via 301. But your solution above keeps everyone on site1.com regardless of user-agent, for me.

Comment: I got it working with your new solution, but without 'NE' part in bottom line, for some reason that caused conflict. Thanks a lot!